# How to set the quality of an mp3 Codec with PyAV

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, codec, pyav

I wrote a simple code to create a .mp3 file from any audio input, using PyAV. It's working (pasted at the end of the question). However, when using `ffmpeg` it's possible to set the quality of the .mp3 file, and I'd like to do this as well in my code. According to the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libmp3lame-1) :

> q (-V)
>
> Set constant quality setting for VBR. This option is valid only using the ffmpeg command-line tool. For library interface users, use `global_quality`.

So, the question is how do I use `global_quality` with PyAV?

I found it at [PyAV documentation](https://pyav.org/docs/develop/development/includes.html), listed as `Wrapped C Types and Functions`, under `struct AVCodecContext`, but I still don't understand how to use this.

I tried creating an `AudioCodecContext` (which is the closest thing to AVCodecContext I found) with `c = av.Codec('mp3').create()`, but it doesn't seem to have a `global_quality` field.

My existing function:

```py
    def encode_audio_to_mp3(input_file_path, output_file_path):
        input_container = av.open(input_file_path)
        output_container = av.open(output_file_path, 'w')
        output_stream = output_container.add_stream('mp3')
    
        for in_packet in input_container.demux():
            for in_frame in in_packet.decode():
                for out_packet in output_stream.encode(in_frame):
                    output_container.mux(out_packet)
    
        # Flush stream
        for packet in output_stream.encode():
            output_container.mux(packet)
    
        output_container.close()
        input_container.close()
```

Comment: This code excerpt can't be complete - of which data types are `av` and `output_container` and `output_stream`? Once you know that, you can see from the documentation upon which property or method you reach something of the data type `AVCodecContext`, where you could then set `.global_quality`. Always show a self-contained code example, completely with variable declarations and imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the audio stream's bitrate, which controls the quality.

```py
import av


def encode_audio_to_mp3(input_path: str, output_path: str) -> None:
    input_ = av.open(input_path)
    output_container = av.open(output_path, "w")

    input_stream = input_.streams.audio[0]
    output_stream = output_container.add_stream("mp3")

    # Set the bitrate for the output stream
    output_stream.bit_rate = 50_000

    for packet in input_.demux(input_stream):
        for frame in packet.decode():
            for out_packet in output_stream.encode(frame):
                output_container.mux(out_packet)

    # Flush stream
    for packet in output_stream.encode():
        output_container.mux(packet)

    output_container.close()
    input_.close()
```